# Convert char array with zero-char element to C# string

Tags: c#, c, arrays, string

When I receive data from unmanaged code written in C (WinAPI) it asks to reserve a number of bytes and pass the handle (pointer) to the string.
Using Marshal.AllocHGlobal(150) didit.
In return, I received the number of chars, terminated by '/0' - C style.
When I build string from this char array using new string(charBuff) it doesn't cut the string at the '/0' point.
Well, I could use Substring + IndexOf, but is there any elegant way to cut it using some special existing method?

Comment: Could you just allocate one less byte to the buffer?  Marshall.AllocHGlobal(149) ?

Comment: @SamAxe Would that cause any sort of buffer overrun? I don't do very much stuff with Marshal, so I honestly don't know.

Comment: Sam is close, but backwards.  Since the string is terminated with '\0' the number of characters is one less than the string length.  So you don't need to use IndexOf, instead just use x.SubString(x.Length - 1).

Comment: This would be easy to answer if you showed code

Comment: When you pass pointer to a buffer to WinAPI, you don't know how long the string will come back. That's why in C - the symbol '\00' is used, to mark the end of the string.
I'm sure C# uses the same convention inside for strings.
That's why my question is not about substrings, indexesOf and such primitive methods of String.

I need something more elegant, maybe inside WinAPI or maybe Mershal contains such methods inherited from C++/C.

In C++ I don't need 2 do extra action like substring. It understands the terminating zero convention by default, by its nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it after wakening up.

It's

> `Marshal.PtrToStringUni(IntPtr)`

```
string MyStringFromWinAPI()
{
string result;
IntPtr strPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(500);
// here would be any API that gets reserved buffer to rerturn string value
SendMessage(camHwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_GET_NAME_UNICODE, 500, strPtr);
// now you could follow 2 ways
// 1-st one is long and boring
char[] charBuff = new char[500];
Marshal.Copy(strPtr, charBuff, 0, 500);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)strPtr);
result = new string(charBuff);
result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf('\0'));
return result;
// or more elegant way
result = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(strPtr);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)strPtr);
return result;
}
```